# Top 10 and Bottom 10 in one report

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to have the Top 10 and Buttom 10 datarecords in one report at the same time. I already started to get top 10 by adding a group and a group sorting. But how do I insert a second group to have the buttom 10 values like this:

```
Top 10:
Group1 Value1
Group1 Value2
Group1 Value3
..
Group1 Value 10


Buttom 10:

Group1 Value1
Group1 Value2
Group1 Value3
..
Group1 Value 10
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Insert a second group after the pagefooter of the first group

Comment: how is this be done in cr13? when i press insert section below there will be just two pagefooters?

Comment: you can do using arrays

Comment: do you have an example for that? pls

Comment: @Simon check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Since you've managed to successfully show first 10, then all you need to do is to show bottoms 10 records. To do that do following steps

- create subreport in report footer or page footer (important thing is if you put it on report footer, you have to check "print on bottom of page" in section expert for that section)
- in subreport in database expert add same datasource as on main report but just sort it by other way (descending)

Design's of both reports (main and subreport) should be the same (only sorting is other) but for iterating twice in separated you need to use subreports because there is no other way to do it.

If you need any more help, feel free to ask. This is only a little guidance to solve your problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. its not possible to use subreports because of perfomance issues... is there any other solution? the data is based on a bw query- so with your solution the query will be executed 2 times - am i right?

Comment: If it's not possible to use subreports, then you should modify your data that you have total of 20 records in your datasource, and first 10 records got 1 column value `top`, last 10 records got column value `bottom` and you make group of that column in report. So either you will prepare your data before generating report, or use subreports.

Comment: Well, first define things what you can do and what you can't in your question. After all cases of things you are allowed to do i can maybe provide you solution.

Comment: its very easy what i can and what not : no subreports and no query modification :)

Comment: Well next time write those informations in question before asking for a solution

Answer (score 0):

try this solution:

Create a array and store values then display.

Place the below formula in details and store data:

```
Shared Numbervar array intarr;

intarr:=intarr+Databasefield;
databasefield
```

Place below formula in group footer:

```
Shared Numbervar array intarr;
Shared Stringvar array firstten;
Shared Stringvar array lastten;
Local Numbervar i;

for i:=1 to 10 do
(

firstten:=firstten+ToText(intarr[i]);
);

for i:=(UBound(intarr)-10) to UBound(intarr) do
(
lastten:=lastten+ToText(intarr[i]);
);

Join(firstten,",")&"-------------"&Join(lastten,",");
```

//firstten has top ten values

//lastten has last ten values

// use and display as required